# connection.close() does not close the connection at server side

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am doing some data validations on Oracle DB. There are 10 different types of validations I have to do. Each set of validation contains hundreds of test cases. To save time, I am running the validations in parallel on 10 different threads. Each thread opens a database connection, execute the test cases and then close the connection - and do the same for the next test case. The problem is that I can have maximum of 8 concurrent oracle sessions. It is currently not possible to increase the number of sessions. To handle this scenario, I am using `Semaphore` to limit the number of concurrent oracle sessions to 8

```
public class DatabaseConnection{
 Semaphore counter = new Semaphore(8);
 public Connection createConnection(){
   ...
   ...
   counter.acquire();
   Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(....
   ...
}

public closeConnection(Connection con){
  ...
  con.close();
  counter.release();
}
}
```

Eventhough I am closing the connections properly after executing each test, I am getting `maximum number of sessions exceeded` exception. I suspects eventhough I close the connections, it is not properly closed at server side. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Either use a debugger to step in `close` and see what is happening or added a debug statement to log `isClosed`

Comment: There are several issues over here. Do not use plain getConnection instead consider something called a connection pool to connect to DB. second is for a priority resource like a database you can exception handling and in finally block mandatorily close the connection. lastly as mentioned by the scary debugger and a detailed review of db server configuration will solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using any connection pool like Hikari? If yes check the size of the pool - should not be greater then 8 in your case.

Comment: @Mar-Z I am not using any connection pool

Comment: @SuchandraT Yes, the code handles exception. I pasted only the important part of the code here

Comment: @ScaryWombat It is hard to debug the issue. There are thousands of test cases, half of them run without any issue. The issue starts when around 50% of the total tests are completed

Answer (score 1):

> I am running the validations in parallel on 10 different threads.

I wonder how are you running the parallel tests? Is it possible that you will end up with 10 instances of the `DatabaseConnection` class? If yes then you will also get 10 semaphores counting 8 times each. In this case the maximum number of connections will be 80... You can avoid it declaring the semaphore as static.

```
static Semaphore counter = new Semaphore(8);
```